# No data returned from getting data from Java resource

Tags: java, file

I have a program which contains a default file (.route). I'm storing it in the jar file at:

```
src/
    resources/
        defaultRoute.route
```

Here is my code:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_ROUTE;

static {

    URL resource = PathCreator.class.getResource("/resources/defaultRoute.route");

    String output = "";
    try {
        output = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(resource.toURI())));
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    DEFAULT_ROUTE = output;

}
```

However, only an empty string is printed to the console. My only guess is that the file path is wrong, but I get a null pointer exception if I change it (so I assume it is correct). My goal is to copy the file to the designated location where the user is creating a new route. I tried lots of techniques, all of which ended with the target file being empty. (In this technique, the string is copied into the new file later.)

Thanks in advance!

In case you are interested, here is the content of the defaultRoute.route file:

```
{
  "route": [],
  "start": {
    "x": "0.0",
    "y": "0.0",
    "angle": "0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work anyway once you package it; you can't reliably use `File` for resources. Use `getResourceAsStream` instead. (Also, there is never a good reason to call `new String(String)`.)

Comment: @chrylis Can you post an example of how to use that? All my attempts have failed. :( Also, the ```new String``` is to convert the byte array to a string. Thanks!

Comment: I missed that you were using `readAllBytes`, sorry; in that case, I'll note that you should always use the constructor that takes a `Charset` (usually UTF-8). You will need to debug your application, stepping through each part of your statement to see what values are returned. I will note that your "default" _looks_ like it should just be a plain "empty" copy of your `Route` class, and JSON doesn't seem to enter into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason, it started working returning the correct data (when exporting and inside eclipse). When attempting @AndrewFomin 's answer, I received a `NullPointerException`. For everyone interested, here is my result, aided by [this](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-array-of-bytes) website:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_ROUTE;

static {

    InputStream resource = PathCreator.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/defaultRoute.route");

    String output = "";
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((nRead = resource.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }

        output = new String(buffer.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    DEFAULT_ROUTE = output;

}
```

I'm not sure why the `resource` folder isn't merging with the `src` folder like everyone was saying in the comments of Andrew Fomin's answer.

Comment: @AndrewFomin For some reason, the file started returning the correct data. However, it only worked with the resources folder still in the path (```/resources/defaultRoute.route```). Do you have any ideas why this might be? When removing the resources part, it also didn't work on the exported .jar.

Comment: this all depends on the way the JAR is built. It is usual to consider src/java and src/resources as "roots", meaning that "java" and "resources" are not part of the path at runtime. But it is possible to configure anything, and apparently, your assembly system is configured to consider src/java as a root (for compiled classes), and src as another (for everything else). A bit strange, but possible. Only way to know would be for you to describe how the jar is built (maven with what pom ? Ant with what script ? Gradle ? ...)

Comment: @GPI I am just using the default for Eclipse. (right-click project > export > runnable jar file)

Answer (score 1):

You should not include 'resources' directory in the resource path. Try this

```
PathCreator.class.getResource("/defaultRoute.route")
```

The first '/' in resource path means resource root dir ('resources' in your case).

Comment: I would not formulate it as "means resource root dir". I would rather say "means classloader root". (Then, the fact that the resources dir is trated in this build as a classpath root by the build process reconciles both views, but it's kinda important to notice that at runtime "/" is no single and specific user directory. It's a root, and each and every component of the classpath can participate in it - modulo classloader visibility).

Comment: You're right. In runtime it's classpath root. But in terms of project structure we can call it resource root, why not. The point is that this code can either produce NPE (if the path is wrong) or read the file correctly. Isn't it?

Comment: I agree that it works. I'm just an overzealous reader that likes to understand / explain why it works, and I would rather leave the reader by seeding the idea that there is more to runtime resource discovery than their "project explorer IDE view" suggests. As your answer stands, one might think that a xyz.route file in the src/java path would not be accessible, because / is src/resources, and not src/java. Oh well... maybe I'm going too far.

Comment: Resource files in src/java are weird:) But your remark is absolutely correct, good expert goes as far as possible! Of coarse, both src/java and src/resources are merged into classpath at runtime